# How to use OKHTTP to make a post request?

Tags: java, okhttp

I read some examples which are posting jsons to the server.

some one says :

> OkHttp is an implementation of the HttpUrlConnection interface
>   provided by Java. It provides an input stream for writing content and
>   doesn't know (or care) about what format that content is.

Now I want to make a normal post to the URL with params of name and password.

It means I need to do encode the name and value pair into stream by myself?

Comment: I wrote an answer to a related question [How to add parameters to api (http post) using okhttp library in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31744565/1276636). It only uses OkHttp.

Comment: Although the marked answer is correct, it only works with versions prior to 3.0. I've added an answer on how it's working now :)

Comment: Here is a complete example of okhttp3 on [how to send post request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795931/android-okhttp-adding-params/38990465#38990465).

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The current accepted answer is out of date. Now if you want to create a post request and add parameters to it you should user MultipartBody.Builder as [Mime Craft now is deprecated](https://github.com/square/mimecraft#deprecated).

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("somParam", "someValue")
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(BASE_URL + route)
        .post(requestBody)
        .build();
```

Comment: I believe the original question had little to nothing to do with Mime Craft. And both the old accepted answer, as the most voted one already answered how to make a POST request with OKHttp versions 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: How to send Integers in request Body?

Comment: Convert the `int` to a `String` @AqibBangash

Comment: To this answer work you should add the content-type header like:

```.addHeader("Content-Type", " application/x-www-form-urlencoded")```

Answer (score 136):

As per [the docs](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), OkHttp version 3 replaced `FormEncodingBuilder` with `FormBody` and `FormBody.Builder()`, so the old examples won't work anymore.

> Form and Multipart bodies are now modeled. We've replaced the opaque
> `FormEncodingBuilder` with the more powerful `FormBody` and
> `FormBody.Builder` combo.
>
> Similarly we've upgraded `MultipartBuilder` into
> `MultipartBody`, `MultipartBody.Part`, and `MultipartBody.Builder`.

So if you're using OkHttp 3.x try the following example:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("message", "Your message")
        .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://www.example.com/index.php")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    // Do something with the response.
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: do we need to implement the above code inside AsyncTask?

Comment: Inside an `AsyncTask`, or `IntentService`, or anywhere except in the main thread :)

Comment: `.add("message", "Your message")` in the `add` method call what is the two string argument? I want to pass only a **body**string content. How?

Comment: First argument is the key, the second is the value.

Comment: I get null response from a call by the above method, while get proper response when I make a call from curl. What could be the reason?

Comment: Hm. That's weird. You could start by checking if the response code is 200 or something else.

Comment: **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

Comment: Don't do it on the main thread. Offload it to another thread. (RxJava, Coroutines, etc)

Comment: I was using Express and NodeJS to receive the request and I could'nt find anything in the body, I had to use body-parser.

Answer (score 38):

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public void run() throws Exception {
    RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
        .add("search", "Jurassic Park")
        .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    System.out.println(response.body().string());
  }
```

Answer (score 19):

You need to encode it yourself by escaping strings with [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and joining them with `"="` and `"&"`. Or you can use [FormEncoder](https://github.com/square/mimecraft/blob/master/src/main/java/com/squareup/mimecraft/FormEncoding.java) from [Mimecraft](https://github.com/square/mimecraft) which gives you a handy builder.

```
FormEncoding fe = new FormEncoding.Builder()
    .add("name", "Lorem Ipsum")
    .add("occupation", "Filler Text")
    .build();
```

Comment: thanks .how to upload a file with okhttp?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512547/how-to-use-okhttp-to-upload-a-file,I think it's a really good libs.

Comment: This is not working on OkHttp 3.x. To see how it works, check my answer :)

Comment: For those looking for GET parameters: Look at the `HttpUrl` class (From the OkHttp lib).

Answer (score 19):

You can make it like this:

```java
    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, "{"jsonExample":"value"}");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Authorization", "header value") //Notice this request has header if you don't need to send a header just erase this part
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);

    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            Log.e("HttpService", "onFailure() Request was: " + request);

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response r) throws IOException {

            response = r.body().string();

            Log.e("response ", "onResponse(): " + response );

        }
    });
```

Comment: deprecated by now

Comment: To fix the deprecated warning, inverse the order of the arguments:
`RequestBody body = RequestBody.create( "{"jsonExample":"value"}",JSON);`

Answer (score 6):

OkHttp `POST` request with token in header

```
       RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("search", "a")
            .addFormDataPart("model", "1")
            .addFormDataPart("in", "1")
            .addFormDataPart("id", "1")
            .build();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url("https://somedomain.com/api")
            .post(requestBody)
            .addHeader("token", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIkMnkkMTAkZzZrLkwySlFCZlBmN1RTb3g3bmNpTzltcVwvemRVN2JtVC42SXN0SFZtbzZHNlFNSkZRWWRlIiwic3ViIjo0NSwiaWF0IjoxNTUwODk4NDc0LCJleHAiOjE1NTM0OTA0NzR9.tefIaPzefLftE7q0yKI8O87XXATwowEUk_XkAOOQzfw")
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .addHeader("Postman-Token", "7e231ef9-5236-40d1-a28f-e5986f936877")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                final String myResponse = response.body().string();

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("response", myResponse);
                        progress.hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

To add okhttp as a dependency do as follows

- right click on the app on android studio open "module settings"
- "dependencies"-> "add library dependency" -> "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0" -> add -> ok..

now you have okhttp as a dependency

Now design a interface as below so we can have the callback to our activity once the network response received.

```
public interface NetworkCallback {

    public void getResponse(String res);
}
```

I create a class named NetworkTask so i can use this class to handle all the network requests

```
    public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String , String, String>{

    public NetworkCallback instance;
    public String url ;
    public String json;
    public int task ;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    public static final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    public NetworkTask(){

    }

    public NetworkTask(NetworkCallback ins, String url, String json, int task){
        this.instance = ins;
        this.url = url;
        this.json = json;
        this.task = task;
    }


    public String doGetRequest() throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }

    public String doPostRequest() throws IOException {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
        try {
            String response = "";
            switch(task){
                case 1 :
                    response = doGetRequest();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    response = doPostRequest();
                    break;

            }
            return response;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        instance.getResponse(s);
    }
}
```

now let me show how to get the callback to an activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NetworkCallback{
    String postUrl = "http://your-post-url-goes-here";
    String getUrl = "http://your-get-url-goes-here";
    Button doGetRq;
    Button doPostRq;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        doGetRq = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    doPostRq = findViewById(R.id.button1);

        doPostRq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.this.sendPostRq();
            }
        });

        doGetRq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.this.sendGetRq();
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendPostRq(){
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jo.put("email", "yourmail");
            jo.put("password","password");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    // 2 because post rq is for the case 2
        NetworkTask t = new NetworkTask(this, postUrl,  jo.toString(), 2);
        t.execute(postUrl);
    }

    public void sendGetRq(){

    // 1 because get rq is for the case 1
        NetworkTask t = new NetworkTask(this, getUrl,  jo.toString(), 1);
        t.execute(getUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void getResponse(String res) {
    // here is the response from NetworkTask class
    System.out.println(res)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the possible solutions to implementing an OKHTTP post request without a request body.

```
RequestBody reqbody = RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]);  
Request.Builder formBody = new Request.Builder().url(url).method("POST",reqbody).header("Content-Length", "0");
clientOk.newCall(formBody.build()).enqueue(OkHttpCallBack());
```

Comment: Above code working fine but i want with requestbody. I tried some examples but not working displaying error :"You don't have permission to access this url"

Answer (score 2):

You should check tutorials on [lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/member.aspx). Here is an example of how to encode the parameters, make HTTP request and then parse response to json object.

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String str_url, List<NameValuePair> params) {      
        String reply_str = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(str_url);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            HttpURLConnection con = client.open(url);                           
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(getEncodedParams(params));
            writer.flush();     
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));           
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }           
            reply_str = sb.toString();              
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object. There are better ways to parse data.
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(reply_str);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {   
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }     
      return jObj;
    }

    //in this case it's NameValuePair, but you can use any container
    public String getEncodedParams(List<NameValuePair> params) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (NameValuePair nvp : params) {
            String key = nvp.getName();
            String param_value = nvp.getValue();
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = URLEncoder.encode(param_value, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("&");
            }
            sb.append(key + "=" + value);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   protected Void doInBackground(String... movieIds) {
                for (; count <= 1; count++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Resources res = getResources();
                String web_link = res.getString(R.string.website);

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("name", name)
                        .add("bsname", bsname)
                        .add("email", email)
                        .add("phone", phone)
                        .add("whatsapp", wapp)
                        .add("location", location)
                        .add("country", country)
                        .add("state", state)
                        .add("city", city)
                        .add("zip", zip)
                        .add("fb", fb)
                        .add("tw", tw)
                        .add("in", in)
                        .add("age", age)
                        .add("gender", gender)
                        .add("image", encodeimg)
                        .add("uid", user_id)
                        .build();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(web_link+"edit_profile.php")
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();

                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);

                    hashMap.put("msg",object.getString("msgtype"));
                    hashMap.put("msg",object.getString("msg"));
                    // Do something with the response.
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                return null;
            }
```

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = null;

                if(selectedphoto!=null) {
                    try {
                        bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(selectedphoto).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    encodeimg = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);
                }

Answer (score 1):

Here is my method to do post request 
first pass in method map and data like

```
HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();

param.put("Name", name);
param.put("Email", email);
param.put("Password", password);
param.put("Img_Name", "");

final JSONObject result = doPostRequest(map,Url);

public static JSONObject doPostRequest(HashMap<String, String> data, String url) {

    try {
        RequestBody requestBody;
        MultipartBuilder mBuilder = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM);

        if (data != null) {


            for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                String value = data.get(key);
                Utility.printLog("Key Values", key + "-----------------" + value);

                mBuilder.addFormDataPart(key, value);

            }
        } else {
            mBuilder.addFormDataPart("temp", "temp");
        }
        requestBody = mBuilder.build();


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String responseBody = response.body().string();
        Utility.printLog("URL", url);
        Utility.printLog("Response", responseBody);
        return new JSONObject(responseBody);

    } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonObject.put("status","false");
            jsonObject.put("message",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonObject.put("status","false");
            jsonObject.put("message",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Other Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the following to the build.gradle

> `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'`

2. Create a new thread, in the new thread add the following code.

> ```
> OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
> MediaType MIMEType= MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
> RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create (MIMEType,"{}");
> Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(requestBody).build();
> Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As for **Kotlin in 2022** (POST request) works:

```
       val client = OkHttpClient()
        val formBody: RequestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
            .addFormDataPart("phone", editText1.text.toString())
            .addFormDataPart("email", editText2.text.toString())
            .build()
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://hellokitty.com/users")
            .post(formBody)
            .build()

        try {
            // Do something with the response.
            val response = client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: okio.IOException) {
                    print(e.message)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    print(response.message)
                    print("XXX \n" + response.body)
                }
            })
            editTextResponse.text = response.toString()

        } catch (e: java.io.IOException) {
            editTextResponse.text = e.toString()
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

**Gradle:**

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.6")
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jaskierltd.blablaApp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post parameter in okhttp as body content which can be encrypted string with content-type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" you can first use URLEncoder to encode the data and then use :

```
final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
    .url(urlOfServer)
    .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN, yourBodyDataToPostOnserver))
    .build();
```

you can add header according to your requirement.

Answer (score -4):

```
 public static JSONObject doPostRequestWithSingleFile(String url,HashMap<String, String> data, File file,String fileParam) {

        try {
            final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");

            RequestBody requestBody;
            MultipartBuilder mBuilder = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM);

            for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                String value = data.get(key);
                Utility.printLog("Key Values", key + "-----------------" + value);

                mBuilder.addFormDataPart(key, value);

            }
            if(file!=null) {
                Log.e("File Name", file.getName() + "===========");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    mBuilder.addFormDataPart(fileParam, file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, file));
                }
            }
            requestBody = mBuilder.build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String result=response.body().string();
            Utility.printLog("Response",result+"");
            return new JSONObject(result);

        } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonObject.put("status","false");
                jsonObject.put("message",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Other Error: " + e.getMessage());
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonObject.put("status","false");
                jsonObject.put("message",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static JSONObject doGetRequest(HashMap<String, String> param,String url) {
        JSONObject result = null;
        String response;
        Set keys = param.keySet();

        int count = 0;
        for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            count++;
            String key = (String) i.next();
            String value = (String) param.get(key);
            if (count == param.size()) {
                Log.e("Key",key+"");
                Log.e("Value",value+"");
                url += key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value);

            } else {
                Log.e("Key",key+"");
                Log.e("Value",value+"");

                url += key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value) + "&";
            }

        }
/*
        try {
            url=  URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        Log.e("URL", url);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        Response responseClient = null;
        try {


            responseClient = client.newCall(request).execute();
            response = responseClient.body().string();
            result = new JSONObject(response);
            Log.e("response", response+"==============");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonObject.put("status","false");
                jsonObject.put("message",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                return  jsonObject;
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Why is there so much code for such a simple thing?  Please explain.