# Upload a file in Android

Tags: java, android

In Android, it seems so confusing how to upload a binary file to a server because some libraries have become outdated and there's a lack of information which approach should be used nowadays.
Could anyone give a pointer of how to upload a binary or whatever file to a server in Android?

I'd prefer not to use any dependencies, unless they really are neccessary.

Comment: Try retrofit it is really helpful for any kind of server interaction!

Answer (score 0):

In lack of information what kind of server this might be, I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512547/how-to-use-okhttp-to-upload-a-file)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
    HttpURLConnection connection = client.open(url);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : multipart.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
        connection.addRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    // Write the request.
    out = connection.getOutputStream();
    multipart.writeBodyTo(out);
    out.close();

    // Read the response.
    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected HTTP response: "
                + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage());
    }
} 
finally {
    try { if (out != null) out.close(); } 
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

I assume that the deprecated/outdated library you mentioned would be [ApacheHttpClient](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client), therefore I recommend `OkHttp` (that is using `HttpUrlConnection`I believe) instead.

To add OkHttp as dependency you can edit your `build.gradle` like:

```
dependencies {
    //some other dependencies
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
}
```

Available versions can be found here: [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp) (no need to download them manually, just add them like above, gradle will download them itself)

Comment: what dependencies should I use and how to add them?

Comment: hey, it seems "client" has no method called "open()".