# How to upload a video using volley

Tags: android, video, android-volley

I have searched all android blogs on how to upload a video in android using volley to no avail. 
Am stuck at the point where am supposed to convert a video to a string.  Similar to the step where you convert an image to bitmap. 
Any source code or pointing me to the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try multipart request that will help you out. here is the reference link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622676/image-upload-using-okhttp/35622812#35622812

you need to change the mime type according to your need.
you can also zip the video file and upload that zip file using multipart request.
mime type for zip is:: application/zip