# How to send big size image to a server in android?

Tags: android, image, matlab, server, send

I have to send a DNG file which has a size around 30 mb to my server and then I have to process DNG file in matlab and after that I need to get the results back from matlab to android device. I am new to sending images to a server and I do not know if is there any special way for big size images. I saw similar questions but I could not understand what to do for sending images to a server.

Could you please help me which steps should I follow respectively and which methods or libraries do I need to use ? Thanks.

Comment: You can [upload image using okhttp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622676/image-upload-using-okhttp/35622812#35622812).

Comment: `I do not know if is there any special way for big size images. ` No that is not needed when you do it right. I wonder why you cannot find code. Your task is pretty common and code you can find all over the internet and on this site. `30 mb` You mean `30 MB` ?

Comment: Yes,I meant 30 MB. Also I found a way which is using ftp server. I hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to send big files using HTTP, chunks are the way to go.

You would need a backend server supporting this kind of operation (either with some homemade recipe or with a standardized implementation).

You'd basically need an API to create the file description (including the expected size) which would return a handle on this future file (at least an ID). Then use PUT or PATCH and send the chunks one by one.