# POST with form-data file with OkHttp3

Tags: android, okhttp, form-data

I am using OkHttp3 and want to achieve the same result as in postman attached file in android:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRp7y4UMDw_b293c2NMbFoxMHc/view?usp=sharing

The call will send POST with "form-data" key:"wav" and the value an attached audio file from resources

A sample code is what I need

Comment: Use multipart Request to upload your audio file.

Comment: For reference you can [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622676/image-upload-using-okhttp/35622812#35622812). you need to just change the mime type and you can easily upload your audio file.