# could not be able to upload file to server using retrofit2

Tags: php, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to upload .pdf file to server where php code is

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","pwd","api_db");

        $user_id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['cvTitle'];

        $allowedExts = array("docx","doc", "pdf", "txt");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['cvfile']["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES["cvfile"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
    || ($_FILES["cvfile"]["type"] == "application/text/plain")
    || ($_FILES["cvfile"]["type"] == "application/msword")
    || ($_FILES["cvfile"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"))
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){

      //inner if
      if ($_FILES["cvfile"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Failed 1";
      } else{

      }// end inner else

      $f_name = time().$_FILES['cvfile']["name"];

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cvfile']["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $f_name);

      $file_name = $f_name;


      } else {

          $json = array("File Type Not Allowed"); 

      header('content-type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($json);
      } // end else 

    $query = "UPDATE users set cv = '$file_name', cvTitle = '$title' where id = '$user_id'";

    if (mysqli_query($db,$query)) {

          $json = array("cv" => $file_name, "cvTitle" => $title); 

      header('content-type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($json);
      }

?>
```

my service is

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @Multipart
    @POST("updatecv.php")
    Call<User> uploadUserCV(@Field("id") String id,
                            @Field("cvTitle") String cvTitle,
                            @Part MultipartBody.Part cv);
```

and finally I'm making call as

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_cv : {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("*/*");

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose file using"), Constant.REQUEST_CODE_OPEN);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            if (requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_CODE_OPEN){
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
                    String type = Utils.getMimeType(UpdateProfileActivity.this, data.getData());
                    if (validateFileType(type)){
                        // Get the Image from data
                        Uri selectedFile = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};

                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedFile, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        assert cursor != null;
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();

                        uploadFile();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(UpdateProfileActivity.this, "File type is not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Log.e("FILE_TYPE", Utils.getMimeType(UpdateProfileActivity.this, data.getData()));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // Uploading CV
    private void uploadFile() {
        final Dialog dialog = Utils.showPreloaderDialog(UpdateProfileActivity.this);
        dialog.show();
        // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
        File file = new File(mediaPath);

        // Parsing any Media type file
        final RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);

        mUserCall = mRestManager.getApiService().uploadUserCV(uid, file.getName(), fileToUpload);
        mUserCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

                User user = response.body();

                Log.e("UPLOADED_FILE", "name is " + user.getCvTitle());

                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("UPLOADED_FILE_ERROR", "Message is " + t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(UpdateProfileActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean validateFileType(String type){
        String [] allowedFileTypes = {"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                                        "application/msword", "text/plain", "application/pdf"};
        for (int i = 0; i<=allowedFileTypes.length; i++){
            if (allowedFileTypes[i].equals(type)){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

but this code is not uploading the file to server no any errors. I wan to know where are the things wrong in php code or in android side.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622676/image-upload-using-okhttp/35622812#35622812). This is just for your reference it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to your PHP, you're looking for form-data part with name `cvfile`, but in Android code you're passing `file` as a name of the form-data part. So all you need is to change `file` to `cvfile`, like this:

```
MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("cvfile", file.getName(), requestBody);
```

Hopefully it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are testing on localhost then inside app localhost url is needed ....to grab that
type ipconfig (in cmd on windows) 
copy that ip which is connected to lan or wifi.
then check is upload.php file present or not on that ip address.
for eg : 192.168.1.102/upload.php
after that  copy the ip and 
add in base url of retrofit builder in retrofit client class.
Hope it will solve your issue :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice but the file I'm testing with remote server not local host, .php is available there as well, but code is not working, any other suggestions to resolve this issue please.