# Uploading Image and Audio in form data with OKhttp giving me BadRequest Status 400

Tags: android, multipartform-data, okhttp

I am using put request to upload image and to the server using Okhttp, the request work fine with the postman, but through android it is giving me bad request
i have implemented the method discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23784452/9145387

Kindly help me out sorting this.... Thanks in Advance

```
 public  Boolean uploadFile(String serverURL, File file) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    try {

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(),
                        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), file))
                .addFormDataPart(caseId+"_audio", caseId+"_audio",
                        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/*"), Audio))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(serverURL)
                .put(requestBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    response.toString();
                    // Handle the error
                }
                // Upload successful
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // Handle the error
    }
    return false;
}
```

[screenshot of the successful upload of image on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVIXv.png)

Comment: Put log into the first position of onFailure, onResponse methods to see whether it go into that or not. Just something like Log.i(TAG, "gotothis");

Comment: i debugged the code, after executing this line client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {} 
it directly goes to return false.

Comment: You mean it will return "false" immediately when you call the function: uploadFile ?

Comment: yes it immediately goes to return false.

Comment: It must be, since this code: client.newCall(request).enqueue will be executed asynchronously. Hence you have to wait for a while to get response from onFailure or onResponse.

Comment: well i have waited for quite long, i have added the breakpoints on the onFailure and on Responce but it doesn't seem to get executed.

Comment: **[obviously you should learn about async calls and multithreading](https://ideone.com/PPHi95)** ... your return statment in this example is 3. ... and onResponse is 2. - as you see obviously program would go to 3 before 2...

Comment: Please try to use log to see if there is any difference since I do not know whether you set up breakpoint correctly

Comment: got it... thanks Cao Minh ... it was getting timeout error... 
can you tell me how can i extend request time ?

Comment: Try Using `MediaType.parse("image/*")`. You are passing .png instead of .jpg.

Comment: hey anyone there, the code is giving me bad request, while with the postman it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the error was in the request body.

```
   RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
            .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), file))
            .addFormDataPart(caseId+"_audio", caseId+"_audio",
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/*"), Audio))
            .build();
```

Changed this line

```
 .addFormDataPart(caseId+"_audio", caseId+"_audio",
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/*"), Audio))
            .build();
```

to

```
   .addFormDataPart(caseId+"_audio", Audio.getName(),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/*"), Audio))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to reset timeout:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
client.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: thanks, but now i am facing bad request, kindly help me out, see the attachment of postman,

Comment: this line .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(), should be changed to: .addFormDataPart("imag", file.getName(),