# How to send FormData with MultiPart request using retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2, image-uploading, multipartform-data, url-encoding

I'm developing an android app where I need to upload multiple images to php server from android app & currently I'm stuck with few questions which are as follow : 
 
 
 1) Can we pass field parameters along with images to upload as Multipart request & if so what should be the correct request format ?
 
 
 2 ) Is below one is the correct way to upload multiple images from Android ?
 
 
 3 ) What should be the correct strategy to upload multiple images smoothly?

Here is my tentative code which I think helps anyone to understand what I'm trying to achieve .

```
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(AppConstants.BASE_URL+AppConstants.POST_AD)
Observable<Response<PostedAd>> postAd(@Header(AppConstants.HEADER_ACCESS_TOKEN) String headerToken,@Part("images[]") RequestBody files, @Field(AppConstants.FIELD_AD_TITLE) String adTitle, @Field(AppConstants.FIELD_AD_DESCRIPTION) String adDesc,@Field(AppConstants.FIELD_AD_ADDRESS) String adAddress,@Field(AppConstants.FIELD_AD_CITY) String city,@Field(AppConstants.FIELD_AD_STATE) String state,@Field(AppConstants.FIELD_AD_ZIPCODE) String zipcode,@Field(AppConstants.FIELD_AD_CONTACT_NUMBER) String contactNumber,@Field(AppConstants.FIELD_AD_TYPE) String adType,@Field(AppConstants.FIELD_AD_BUDGET_RATE) String adbudgetOrRate);
```

**Note :** REST APIs are designed in such way that it doesn't allow me to send all fields as Single Body parameter.

Comment: This is not a pro opinion but, I ran into this in some on my projects... Had to create separate requests on server-side for pictures and rest of my data. Also, usually I create a DataModel class for the body. Another approach, was to use `@Path("url_path")` and Multipart in body of the request.

Comment: okay , I have just updated my question for REST api design & unfortunately I can't send body as parameter . I know it's bad design but I can't do anything about it. 
I'll check for @Path request.

Comment: if you are fine with using okhtpp you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512547/how-to-use-okhttp-to-upload-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to my problem . Basically my problem was to send form data with multiple images & it's present in Retrofit2 .

So , anyone looking for the same kind of requirement then here are links which might help you :

[Send Request Parameters with MultiPart Request using PartMap](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap)
[Upload multiple images using Retrofit2](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-server)

Combine both of these solution together & you can send request parameters along with multiple files.