# Java FX connection with Firebase Storage for uploading pictures

Tags: java, firebase, javafx, firebase-storage

I am working java FX application and I want to upload images from application to `firebase` storage.
I have integrated `firebase` admin `SDK` for core java.
Now I can manage `firebase` database easily. But now, I want to work on Uploading images and I could not find any example or tutorial that is easy or understandable.
All I found, is related to android but I need it in core java.
Please **suggest** me proper example or help me out.
I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [OkHTTP](https://square.github.io/okhttp/). It works for both Android and pure Java. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23784452/9648) gives you a template for uploading.