# How to add parameters to api (http post) using okhttp library in Android

Tags: android, okhttp

In my Android application, I am using [okHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library. How can I send parameters to the server(api) using the okhttp library? currently I am using the following code to access the server now need to use the okhttp library.

this is the my code:

```
httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/user/login.json");
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email".trim(), emailID));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password".trim(), passWord));
httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
String response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost, new BasicResponseHandler());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456488/how-to-use-okhttp-to-make-a-post-request

Comment: Here is a complete example of [How to send post request using okhttp3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795931/android-okhttp-adding-params/38990465#38990465).

Answer (score 53):

For OkHttp 3.x, FormEncodingBuilder was removed, use FormBody.Builder instead

```
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("email", "Jurassic@Park.com")
                .add("tel", "90301171XX")
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
```

Comment: How can I add keys & params to formBody ? I get both "email" and "Jurassic@Park.com" dynamically and I have to have a RequestBody. Thanks.

Comment: @Alvin Yes, definitely. Just do it in such way, `RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add(dynamicEmailKey, dynamicEmailParam)
                .build();`

Comment: @Bao Le, why isn't version 3.x available on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp)?

Comment: okhttp3 uses persistent versioning and puts the version in the group id and package names http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp

Comment: Other solutions are based on older versions of OkHttp. This one is the most updated.

Answer (score 46):

```
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

      public void run() throws Exception {
        RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
            .add("email", "Jurassic@Park.com")
            .add("tel", "90301171XX")
            .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

        System.out.println(response.body().string());
      }
```

Answer (score 7):

You just need to format the body of the POST before creating the `RequestBody` object.

You could do this manually, but I'd suggest you use the [MimeCraft](https://github.com/square/mimecraft) library from Square (makers of OkHttp).

In this case you'd need the [`FormEncoding.Builder`](https://github.com/square/mimecraft/blob/master/src/main/java/com/squareup/mimecraft/FormEncoding.java) class; set the `contentType` to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and use `add(name, value)` for each key-value pair.

Comment: While your are checking out MimeCraft, you might want to check out Retrofit (also by Square) if your ultimate goal is a Restful api

Comment: does this work with `get` requests as well? I mean when `FormEncoding.Builder` is used with `get` requests, are the parameters added to the url?

Comment: To answer my own question, when `FormEncoding.Builder` is used with `GET` requests, `OkHttp` throws an exception something like `GET requests doesn't support request body`.

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers worked for me, so I played around and below one worked fine. Sharing just in case someone gets stuck with the same issue:

Imports:

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
```

Code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
        .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM) //this is what I say in my POSTman (Chrome plugin)
        .addFormDataPart("name", "test")
        .addFormDataPart("quality", "240p")
        .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(myUrl)
        .post(requestBody)
        .build();
try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String responseString = response.body().string();
    response.body().close();
    // do whatever you need to do with responseString
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually to avoid Exceptions brought about by the code running in UI thread, run the request and response process in a worker thread (Thread or Asynch task) depending on the anticipated length of the process.

```
    private void runInBackround(){

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                //method containing process logic.
                makeNetworkRequest(reqUrl);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void makeNetworkRequest(String reqUrl) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Booking started: ");
       OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
       String responseString = "";

       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
       String booked_at = sdf.format(c.getTime());

         try{
             RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("place_id", id)
                .add("booked_at", booked_at)
                .add("booked_by", user_name.getText().toString())
                .add("booked_from", lat+"::"+lng)
                .add("phone_number", user_phone.getText().toString())
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(reqUrl)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        Response response = httpClient
                .newCall(request)
                .execute();
        responseString =  response.body().string();
        response.body().close();
        Log.d(TAG, "Booking done: " + responseString);

        // Response node is JSON Object
        JSONObject booked = new JSONObject(responseString);
        final String okNo = booked.getJSONArray("added").getJSONObject(0).getString("response");
        Log.d(TAG, "Booking made response: " + okNo);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                if("OK" == okNo){
                    //display in short period of time
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Booking Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    //display in short period of time
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Booking Not Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I hope it helps someone there.

Comment: That was what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Another way (without MimeCraft), is to do :

```
    parameters = "param1=text&param2=" + param2  // for example !
    request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url + path)
            .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN, parameters))
            .build();
```

and declare :

```
    public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN = MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

(Kotlin version)
You would need:

```
...
val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
    .add("your_key", "your_value")
    .build()
val newRequest: Request.Builder = Request.Builder()
    .url("api_url")
    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .post(formBody)
...
```

Then, if you have a nodejs express server with npm body-parser installed, be sure to do following:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Version:**

```
fun requestData(url: String): String {

    var formBody: RequestBody = FormBody.Builder()
        .add("email", "Jurassic@Park.com")
        .add("tel", "90301171XX")
        .build();

    var client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient();
    var request: Request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

    var response: Response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body?.toString()!!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send Post data through API using OKHTTP 3 please try below simple code

```
MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        String url = "https://cakeapi.trinitytuts.com/api/add";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        JSONObject postdata = new JSONObject();
        try {
            postdata.put("username", "name");
            postdata.put("password", "12345");
        } catch(JSONException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, postdata.toString());

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                String mMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
                Log.w("failure Response", mMessage);
                //call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                String mMessage = response.body().string();
                Log.e(TAG, mMessage);
            }
        });
```

You can read the complete tutorial to send data to server using OKHTTP 3 GET and POST request here:- https://trinitytuts.com/get-and-post-request-using-okhttp-in-android-application/