# Post a request in java

Tags: java, post

Recently I want use a search interface.But I am confused by the request body.
According to reference,when you need to search in their site,you can do like this:

```
curl -d "keyword=android" http://gankio.herokuapp.com/search
```

So how to post a this request in java rather than curl?

I have tried useing okhttp.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    String json = "keyword=android";
                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON,json);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://gankio.herokuapp.com/search")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                Log.d("TAG",response.body().string());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();`
```

Comment: I'd look for a library to simplify your life. Idk if any good but https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request#perform-a-post-request-with-some-data-and-get-the-status-of-the-response is 1 line of code.

Comment: Is curl working and your code results in a http 400 error? `curl -d` sends data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not as json. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233632/how-to-add-parameters-to-api-http-post-using-okhttp-library-in-android would be the way to do that with OkHttp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this question.

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder().add("keyword", "android").build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://gankio.herokuapp.com/search")
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                Log.d("TAG", response.body().string());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using HttpUrlConnection from java.net 
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116961/can-you-explain-the-httpurlconnection-connection-process) will explain HttpUrlConnection connection process.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call the service using post request and form param, please use the below code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("http://gankio.herokuapp.com/search?keyword=android")
      .post( RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), ""))
      .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        System.out.println(response.body().string());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

The service that you want to call does not need any body to pass, only it needs form parameter (**keyword**) with value (**android**), but you are trying to pass the parameter using the body, and this is your mistake

Comment: First of all thank you.' request.post(null) ' is forbidden.

Comment: Yes I use the latest version.You have pointed my mistake.Thanks very much