# How will i post username and password in ok http

Tags: php, android

i have used http to post body to server now i want to post body through okhttp
i am a new in programming so please describe briefly
please modify the given code to okkhttp post request
please breifly describe how to post body in ok http
thanks in advance

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (emailLogin.getText().toString().length()>3 &&
                    passwordLogin.getText().toString().length()>4){

                emailText=emailLogin.getText().toString();
                passwordText=passwordLogin.getText().toString();

                new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        String response;
                        String body="email="+emailText+"&password="+passwordText;
                        response=http.postRequest(HttpConfigs.URL_AUTH,body);
                        return response;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
                        super.onPostExecute(response);
                        try {
                            final JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
                            remoteMessage=responseJson.getString("message");
                            if (responseJson.getBoolean("result")){
                                showMessage(remoteMessage);
                                JSONObject data = responseJson.getJSONObject("data");
                                Log.d("WaseemTest","Data"+data);
                                 auto login
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }else{
                                showMessage(remoteMessage);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i have tried this
                okHttpClient= new OkHttpClient();
           
                request=new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

Comment: i want to post username and password to server how can i post..can i use asyntask to post data like above

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("somParam", "someValue")
                .build();

        request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BASE_URL + route)
                .method("POST", RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]))
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
```

for further information you may refer below link
[How to use OKHTTP to make a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456488/how-to-use-okhttp-to-make-a-post-request)

Comment: what is route here in (BASE_URL + route)

Comment: method name defined over the web server