# Convert a existent http request from javascript to java

Tags: javascript, java, http, post

So I have this javascript function, and I want to convert it to a java function. This is the original function:

```
function mailExistsCheck() {
request({
    uri: "https://iag.ksmobile.net/1/cgi/is_exist",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': "FBAndroidSDK.0.0.1", DONE
        'Accept-Language': "en_US", DONE
        'appid': "135301",
        'ver': "3.8.20",
        'sid': "17DBB0C2B30D01B590B704501A8AC054",
        'sig': "lbOfPDrq0kJNvZX8eYZH9c0Mo7o",
        'Host': "iag.ksmobile.net",
        'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f",
        'Transfer-Encoding': "chunked",
        'Accept-Encoding': "gzip"
    },
    body: `--3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cmversion"

        38201849
        --3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

        ` + address + `
        --3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f`
}, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    if (body.indexOf("12018") != -1) {

        register();

    } else {
        console.error(body);
        console.error("MAIL EXISTENCE CHECK FAILED!");
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

I'm using this library http://kevinsawicki.github.io/http-request/ to create the http request, so far I have this:

```
public static String mailexiste(String address) {
String contentType = HttpRequest.post("https://iag.ksmobile.net/1/cgi/is_exist")
        .userAgent("FBAndroidSDK.0.0.1")
        .header("Accept-Language", "en_US")
        .header("appid", "135301")
        .header("ver", "3.8.20")
        .header("sid", "17DBB0C2B30D01B590B704501A8AC054")
        .header("sig", "lbOfPDrq0kJNvZX8eYZH9c0Mo7o")
        .header("Host", "iag.ksmobile.net")
        .contentType("multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f")
        .acceptGzipEncoding()
        .contentType(); //Gets response header


return contentType;
```

I think I did the headers the right way, my only issue is that I'm having problems with the body part. I don't understand most of this requests, because I'm just starting now to learn this, and I would like to do the program by myself, but I'm really stuck on this part. Also, how do I do the if's in java? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're better off using [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). Look into how to send [form data with okhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456488/how-to-use-okhttp-to-make-a-post-request).

Comment: I will take a look at it @Ahmad ty

Comment: I thinks you can use this [method](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request/blob/2d62a3e9da726942a93cf16b6e91c0187e6c0136/lib/src/main/java/com/github/kevinsawicki/http/HttpRequest.java#L3045) to set any string for body

Answer (score 1):

- Drop the boundary - unless your server is non-HTTP-compliant, any string should do
- Drop the `Host` header, it will be added by the library automatically
- Use `.part(String name,String value)` to add parts in a multipart:

You should get something like:

```
   .contentType("multipart/form-data")
   .part("cmversion", "38201849")
   .part(name, address)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try when I get home again, but seems promissing! Thanks!

Comment: I did that, but I always get "application/json; charset=utf-8" as a answer... The string always return that...

Comment: Looks like you're reading the wrong parts of the string? I'd suggest you use something like `curl` or Postman to accurately replay the HTTP request, *then* try to map it to Java.

Comment: It works with javascript, so I think the http request is ok

Answer (score 0):

if() is pretty much the same in Java as in JavaScript.

Comment: I know that, I asked about the if's, in like, how can I determinate if the answer is error, etc... Also, my main  issue is the body part