# How to HTTP POST parameters with Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, http, post

I'm struggling to find good examples on how to POST key value pairs to a URL with Android in Java.

Here is what the Android documentation says (and pretty much every other example):

```
URL url = new URL(params[0]);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

try {
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    writeStream(out);

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);

} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

How do I implement `writeStream`?

Many other examples with POST put the parameters in the URL (a=1&b=2&c=3...), but then I could just use GET (?). And I don't want to place the parameters in the URL because that increases the chance of sensitive information to be logged on the server side.

Chrome POSTs data as such (body):

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryyr0AtYZxcOCCp7hA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parameterNameHere"

valueHere
------WebKitFormBoundaryyr0AtYZxcOCCp7hA--
```

Does the Android framework support this?
If not, are there any good libraries?

EDIT:

This is not a duplication of what was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android). What was suggested does in no way answer the question, in that it does not show how to post with parameters, which is what this question is about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending POST data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)

Comment: @sfat Not a duplication. If you read my question, surely you would see that I wanted to post parameters.

Comment: `And I don't want to place the parameters in the URL because that increases the chance of sensitive information to be logged on the server side.` Then put them in the request body. I don't understand what you mean by `post parameters`. In the given url, it is passed in the body

Comment: Yes, I want to place them in the request body. My question is: How do I do that? In the given url, there is only data. Not parameters.

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/13629/okhttp-android-example-tutorial#okhttp-android-post-example I would say don't go with the `HttpURLConnection`. It's pretty low level in regards to interacting with HTTP. Go with something like in the example, as OkHttp or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many libraries out there that would help you achieve this. One of the libraries I use the most is OkHTTP. Include this library in your gradle and check the post from 'mauker' for an example on how to post

[How to use OKHTTP to make a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456488/how-to-use-okhttp-to-make-a-post-request)