# Code for Okhttp client for following requirement

Tags: java, okhttp

I have been learning OkHttpClient using java IN this process I have got stuck with the below one. I dont know How to implement this using OkHttpClient.

```
POST https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50X2lkOmNsaWVudCBzZWNyZXQ=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id=22942C&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffitbit_auth
&code=1234567890
```

Basically the above one in the box is used for Authorization Code Grant Flow
So I want to implement the above one using OkHttpClient using java
Thankyou

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456488/how-to-use-okhttp-to-make-a-post-request) will help you

Comment: This example should help. https://square.github.io/okhttp/#post-to-a-server